# echoing the absolute path of new directory on doing cd

Tags: unix, terminal, konsole

Whenever I do a "cd" at the Konsole, I get a warning msg

> (echo: Command not found.

I think this happens because Konsole tries to output the path to the new directory, but instead of doing **echo $cwd**, I've done **(echo $cwd**. Now, I dont remember where I did this. Its not in my .cshrc, nor in my .cshrc_user file. Where else should I look for it? It'll also be fine if I can just turn off this feature, but how can I do that?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe it's in `.login`?

Comment: What's your shell? Does `\cd` work? Is this a Linux system or have you installed KDE on a Unix box?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see what is in your PS1 variable.

You can try something like this in your home directory to find which file you modified it with:

```
grep PS1 .[a-zA-Z0-9]*
```

I personally like to use:

```
export PS1="\\\${PWD}
\`/usr/xpg4/bin/id -un\`@\`uname -n\`$ "
```

The location of the "id" executable might be different for you. Try this to find out where it is:

```
type id
```

You need one that takes the parameters "-un"